# Is it possible to control an app from displaying the 'Copied to clipboard' message on iOS/Android?

Tags: android, ios

As per the title, I would like to ask if it is possible to control the 'Copied to clipboard' message from the OS level from being displayed in the application.

I am planning to display a custom message with our company's icon added to this message, but I have no idea whether this plan is feasible.

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify even more as what you are exactly looking at? Maybe with screenshot as what you want to achieve. Add some sample code that you have already tried so far to achieve.